# MS SQL Query with MAX Case Problem with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I need some Help with this query:

```
SELECT cKundenNr, cFirma,
MAX(CASE WHEN tAttributSprache.cName = 'Objekt Adresse_A' THEN cWertVarchar else null end) AS "Objektadresse",
MAX(CASE WHEN tAttributSprache.cName = 'Tor Prüftermin_A2' THEN dWertDateTime else null end) AS "Tor Prüftermin"
FROM dbo.tAttribut
JOIN kunde.tKundeEigenesFeld ON kunde.tKundeEigenesFeld.kAttribut = dbo.tAttribut.kAttribut
JOIN tAttributSprache ON tAttributSprache.kAttribut = kunde.tKundeEigenesFeld.kAttribut 
JOIN tkunde ON tkunde.kKunde = kunde.tKundeEigenesFeld.kKunde
JOIN tAdresse ON tAdresse.kKunde = Kunde.tKundeEigenesFeld.kKunde
WHERE cKundenNr = '1121'
```

With this query I get an error.
I understand since yet that I cant take the columns cKundenNr and cFirma in this Query. But
I need them too.
How I have to write the Query?

In the SQL Server Manager I get this:

> The tcustomer.cCustomerID column is invalid in the select list because
> it is not in an aggregate function and is not in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Just add a "GROUP BY cKundenNr, cFirma"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell without sample data and the desired response, but it looks like you're missing the `group by` clause:

```sql
SELECT cKundenNr, cFirma,
MAX(CASE WHEN tAttributSprache.cName = 'Objekt Adresse_A' THEN cWertVarchar else null end) AS "Objektadresse",
MAX(CASE WHEN tAttributSprache.cName = 'Tor Prüftermin_A2' THEN dWertDateTime else null end) AS "Tor Prüftermin"
FROM dbo.tAttribut
JOIN kunde.tKundeEigenesFeld ON kunde.tKundeEigenesFeld.kAttribut = dbo.tAttribut.kAttribut
JOIN tAttributSprache ON tAttributSprache.kAttribut = kunde.tKundeEigenesFeld.kAttribut 
JOIN tkunde ON tkunde.kKunde = kunde.tKundeEigenesFeld.kKunde
JOIN tAdresse ON tAdresse.kKunde = Kunde.tKundeEigenesFeld.kKunde
WHERE cKundenNr = '1121'
GROUP BY cKundenNr, cFirma -- Here!
```